# AngularJS ngOptions search filter - remove duplicate select options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a de-normalized api which returns the following denormalized collection of products.

```
id
name
type
product_type_id
country
product_country_id
created_at
updated_at
```

I can display all results in a table using ngRepeat. I have created a select filter to filter out the products based on their type.

The problem is that in my collection - the type column is not unique.

My Select Filter:

```
<select
    class="form-control"
    data-ng-model="search.product_type_id"
    data-ng-options="product.product_type_id as product.type for product in products">
    <option value="">Filter Product Types</option>
</select>
```

My table ngRepeat:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="product in products | filter : { search : '!null'}">
    <td><% product.type %></td>
    <td><% product.country %></td>
    <td><% product.name %></td>
    <td class="hidden-xs"><% product.created_at %></td>
    <td class="hidden-xs"><% product.updated_at %></td>
    <td>Actions</td>
</tr>
```

Is there a shortcut to only displaying unique product.type in products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use angular-ui's unique filter, should do what you want.

You can read about it [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/).

And use it like this:

```
<select
    class="form-control"
    data-ng-model="search.product_type_id"
    data-ng-options="product.product_type_id as product.type for product in products | unique:'type'">
    <option value="">Filter Product Types</option>
</select>
```